# How can I fix latch in locking mechanism and align a bifold door?

Tags: doors, lock

The Origin bifold doors we have to the garden have been a little bit fiddly since we moved in.

Sometimes the locking mechanism (turn handle up) would stick and it required a lot of strength to lock. It has got to the point where it is not possible to lock it any more.

At the beginning I thought it was consequence of the door being a little bit misaligned - it leaves a tiny gap on the top when closed, but after carefully examination it seems to be all related to the locking mechanism in the door itself, not the frame.

One of the latches won't come out as it hits the metal inner plate. It is a bit loose (as they are the other latches) and pushing it upwards a bit with the finger and locking the door (with the door open) makes it come out ok. It basically hits the metal plate on the bottom.

I have tried fixing the screws along the plate with the latch out just in case it was a matter of getting the plate a little bit deeper, but that has not helped. Any ideas how can I try to fix it? Would the whole lock mechanism need to be changed? or the metal plate moved ?

---

As recommended in the comments I have filed the latch and now comes out of the door without problems, however the door still struggles to lock. So I guess I need to align the gap on top. Included new pictures showing the way the door attaches to the wells in the rail.

The new question is - how can I adjust the door to align it? It doesn't looks clear where is an screw/bold I can tight

The gap
[image: The gap]

Lower wheels
[image: Lower wells]

Upper wheels
[image: Upper wells]

Upper hinge - up
[image: Upper hinge - up]

Upper hinge - bottom
[image: Upper hinge - bottom]

Comment: The gap might have helped.  Forcing the latch when in the locked position.  Will need to find exactly where the binding is happening.  If just a simple latch catching on the frame, maybe a bit of grinding/filing to clear the opening.  If it the latch mechanism, tend might be more involved.

Comment: Thanks @crip659. Pretty sure it is the latch catching on the frame, si going to try a bit of filling, not sure if I have a proper file so may need to get one

Comment: Agree that filing the plate a little probably won't hurt. When you have the long plate off, a little lube at pivot points would be good.

Comment: I couldn't file the plate with what I have at hand, but filled the latch a little bit and now it comes out perfectly! Sally looks like there is something else going on - I think it doesn't close enough and touch in the metal plate on the frame. I will update the post, and I'll try some more lube after the filing, it didn't help much before

Comment: If the door sifted a bit(the gap) it probably also not inline for the door frame catch either.

Comment: Yeah I think that is. Not sure how to align it though :(, haven't found much about origin ones in YouTube or their website. A little bit of WD-40 have helped though, it requires qué a bit of strength but at least I can lock it now

Comment: Check the hinge screws, top ones might be loose or could be tighter.

Comment: Adjust the wheels

Comment: I have added some new pictures of the hinges/wheels. I cannot see where I can tighten them. There are some bols on the upper one that may be? Or the screw in the hinge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to close the loop. I ended up calling the installers and they fix it differently.

They removed the glass panels and added some plastic pieces between the glass panel and the frame that made the glass panel push the frame to cover the gap.

So it wasn't a matter of the hinges being loose, and it was something I wouldn't have dare to do myself!

Comment: Thanks for the update! You may want to change the check mark to your answer for future readers so they know what actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

They will sag over time.

As indicated by the gap at the top.

Open the top cover so you can see the wells and some bolts/ screws.

Adjust the hight of the wells ,till the sag is gone.

Comment: Thanks, top cover of the hinges?

Comment: of the door rail, where the wells are

Comment: Thanks @Ruskes. I have updated with some picures of the wells not sure what I need to adjust in there